# Can you use &: instead of &method in ruby 2.5 with a #yield_self?

Tags: ruby

Since the release of Ruby 2.5 we have been given the new `#yield_self` method. I think this is a fantastic addition as finally I can string large active record scopes (conditionally) together.

However, while reading [this page](https://medium.com/tailor-tech/whats-new-in-ruby-2-6-a4774f3631c1) it has the following example:

```
Event.upcoming
  .yield_self { |events| params[:limit]  ? events.limit(params[:limit]) : events }
  .yield_self { |events| params[:status] ? events.where(status: params[:status]) : events }
# Or even
Event.upcoming
  .yield_self { |_| params[:limit] ? _.limit(params[:limit]) : _ }
  .yield_self { |_| params[:status] ? _.where(status: params[:status]) : _ }
# Or even
def with_limit(events)
  params[:limit] ? events.limit(params[:limit]) : events
end
def with_status(events)
  params[:status] ? events.where(status: params[:status]) : events
end
Event.upcoming
  .yield_self(&method(:with_limit))
  .yield_self(&method(:with_status))
```

Which is exactly what I want to do, however I was wondering, regarding the bottom bit, could you write this instead?

```
Event.upcoming
  .yield_self(&:with_limit)
  .yield_self(&:with_status)
```

Or do you specifically need the `&method` part to call the methods properly with yield_self?

Comment: A tiny detail: `Object#yield_self` made its debut in v2.5; `Object#then`, an alias, came out in v2.6. I personally prefer the latter, for readability.

Comment: Ahh, true...I was going to use #then in my actual code, but thought I'd use the original example for clarity.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It doesn't work in my example, but why? Is there another way to pass the parameter into &: without &method?